# how to get rgbdslam map data?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using kinect for SLAM. In this process I can get the map generated using rgbdslam package but I don't know how to obtain the rgb and depth data generated by the sensor. Where exactly is the map or better say the rgbd data stored and how can I obtain it?

I am new to this thing so I cannot provide much detail. If somebody could provide the answer it would be very helpful....if you need some detail from my side please ask for it...
I am using ROS electric on Ubuntu 11.10..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36080/how-to-get-rgbdslam-map-data?/) by [shubh991](https://answers.ros.org/users/2567/shubh991/) on ROS Answers with karma: 105 on 2012-06-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should record these topics in a bag file:

```
/camera/depth/camera_info
/camera/depth/image
/camera/rgb/camera_info
/camera/rgb/image_color
/tf
```

They have all the info for use with RGBDSLAM. Then, use that package to map with the simulated data. You can save the map in the GUI supplied with the RGBDSLAM package.

If you are just trying to make a 2D map, then record

```
/tf
/scan
```

and use the gmapping package to map. Use the map_server package to save a map.

Hope it helps!

-Hunter A.

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2012-06-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0